# htaccess URL Rewrite not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to set up htaccess to redirect all the site to HTTPS with the exception of a single page (www.realcoach.com/feed/podcasts).  The follow doesn't seem to be working.

```
# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[2.3.9]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feed
RewriteRule !^feed($|/) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
```

This still redirects the feed page as well to https. What am I missing?

Comment: Probably 'HTTPSEverywhere' extension in your browser?

Comment: Nope it's definitely site related.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try again as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feed
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Same issue.  I'm now thinking there is some other code in play in the install that is overriding this perhaps.